# Scheduling a set of matchups so each participant's matchups aren't too close together

Tags: javascript, algorithm, combinatorics

**Main goal:**

To create a JavaScript function that will help each fighter to have a better sequence of fight. Some of the fighters have seven entries in the whole event. In the `fighter1` and `fighter2` columns, in the given data you can see the fightNumber of every fighter. The gap per fighter with same name is too close or too far. Our targets are:

1. The gap on every fighter with same name should have 10 to 30 fightNumber difference. 10 is the minimum gap and the 30 was the
   maximum gap.
2. `fightNumber should be unique that will range only from 1 to 162. (No duplicate of fight number)

**Object data:**

1. id = fight id
2. **fighter1** and **fighter2** = these are the fighters that will be matched. fighter1 vs. fighter2
   -fighter has a different name. Each name possible is to be in fighter1 or fighter2
3. fightNumber - this is the unique sequence number of each fight. It can be updated once the new generation of sequence (range of this is
   from 1 to the total of length of entry data (For this testing, I have
   162 fights))

Purpose of creating this function:

This will help every fighter not to wait too long or too short that we need to give gap 10 - 30 fightNumber difference.

My goal is for example:

**Fighter 1: 'V' is fightNumber 1**. Its next fight should be **10 (Minimum)**
**or 30 (Maximum)**. But in my current function, it got a match again at
**fightNumber 6 (which is equal to 5 fightNumber difference only)**.

It means that my current function didn't meet my condition which is
equal to (please see the above conditions).

I think I'm having a problem regarding my condition. Is there a way where I can achieve my goal?

```js
  const data = [
    { id: "1", fighter1: "V", fighter2: "DD", fightNumber: 1 },
    { id: "2", fighter1: "R", fighter2: "V", fightNumber: 2 },
    { id: "3", fighter1: "J", fighter2: "X", fightNumber: 3 },
    { id: "4", fighter1: "H", fighter2: "KK", fightNumber: 4 },
    { id: "5", fighter1: "DD", fighter2: "MM", fightNumber: 5 },
    { id: "6", fighter1: "V", fighter2: "Z", fightNumber: 6 },
    { id: "7", fighter1: "V", fighter2: "SS", fightNumber: 7 },
    { id: "8", fighter1: "C", fighter2: "V", fightNumber: 8 },
    { id: "9", fighter1: "P", fighter2: "joker", fightNumber: 9 },
    { id: "10", fighter1: "P", fighter2: "LL", fightNumber: 10 },
    { id: "11", fighter1: "Y", fighter2: "QQ", fightNumber: 11 },
    { id: "12", fighter1: "R", fighter2: "OO", fightNumber: 12 },
    { id: "13", fighter1: "D", fighter2: "R", fightNumber: 13 },
    { id: "14", fighter1: "X", fighter2: "DD", fightNumber: 14 },
    { id: "15", fighter1: "P", fighter2: "W", fightNumber: 15 },
    { id: "16", fighter1: "Y", fighter2: "BB", fightNumber: 16 },
    { id: "17", fighter1: "D", fighter2: "O", fightNumber: 17 },
    { id: "18", fighter1: "W", fighter2: "CC", fightNumber: 18 },
    { id: "19", fighter1: "JJ", fighter2: "KK", fightNumber: 19 },
    { id: "20", fighter1: "I", fighter2: "T", fightNumber: 20 },
    { id: "21", fighter1: "T", fighter2: "MM", fightNumber: 21 },
    { id: "22", fighter1: "R", fighter2: "RR", fightNumber: 22 },
    { id: "23", fighter1: "T", fighter2: "FF", fightNumber: 23 },
    { id: "24", fighter1: "G", fighter2: "DD", fightNumber: 24 },
    { id: "25", fighter1: "L", fighter2: "FF", fightNumber: 25 },
    { id: "26", fighter1: "S", fighter2: "EE", fightNumber: 26 },
    { id: "27", fighter1: "BB", fighter2: "GG", fightNumber: 27 },
    { id: "28", fighter1: "E", fighter2: "MM", fightNumber: 28 },
    { id: "29", fighter1: "J", fighter2: "T", fightNumber: 29 },
    { id: "30", fighter1: "V", fighter2: "X", fightNumber: 30 },
    { id: "31", fighter1: "CC", fighter2: "DD", fightNumber: 31 },
    { id: "32", fighter1: "Q", fighter2: "EE", fightNumber: 32 },
    { id: "33", fighter1: "C", fighter2: "T", fightNumber: 33 },
    { id: "34", fighter1: "H", fighter2: "U", fightNumber: 34 },
    { id: "35", fighter1: "Z", fighter2: "II", fightNumber: 35 },
    { id: "36", fighter1: "A", fighter2: "JJ", fightNumber: 36 },
    { id: "37", fighter1: "H", fighter2: "T", fightNumber: 37 },
    { id: "38", fighter1: "D", fighter2: "OO", fightNumber: 38 },
    { id: "39", fighter1: "L", fighter2: "O", fightNumber: 39 },
    { id: "40", fighter1: "T", fighter2: "DD", fightNumber: 40 },
    { id: "41", fighter1: "F", fighter2: "MM", fightNumber: 41 },
    { id: "42", fighter1: "N", fighter2: "V", fightNumber: 42 },
    { id: "43", fighter1: "X", fighter2: "EE", fightNumber: 43 },
    { id: "44", fighter1: "G", fighter2: "PP", fightNumber: 44 },
    { id: "45", fighter1: "I", fighter2: "Q", fightNumber: 45 },
    { id: "46", fighter1: "K", fighter2: "CC", fightNumber: 46 },
    { id: "47", fighter1: "F", fighter2: "DD", fightNumber: 47 },
    { id: "48", fighter1: "Q", fighter2: "AA", fightNumber: 48 },
    { id: "49", fighter1: "AA", fighter2: "PP", fightNumber: 49 },
    { id: "50", fighter1: "LL", fighter2: "TT", fightNumber: 50 },
    { id: "51", fighter1: "P", fighter2: "Z", fightNumber: 51 },
    { id: "52", fighter1: "W", fighter2: "FF", fightNumber: 52 },
    { id: "53", fighter1: "MM", fighter2: "RR", fightNumber: 53 },
    { id: "54", fighter1: "FF", fighter2: "II", fightNumber: 54 },
    { id: "55", fighter1: "F", fighter2: "P", fightNumber: 55 },
    { id: "56", fighter1: "G", fighter2: "MM", fightNumber: 56 },
    { id: "57", fighter1: "O", fighter2: "BB", fightNumber: 57 },
    { id: "58", fighter1: "H", fighter2: "PP", fightNumber: 58 },
    { id: "59", fighter1: "K", fighter2: "O", fightNumber: 59 },
    { id: "60", fighter1: "P", fighter2: "BB", fightNumber: 60 },
    { id: "61", fighter1: "HH", fighter2: "KK", fightNumber: 61 },
    { id: "62", fighter1: "B", fighter2: "K", fightNumber: 62 },
    { id: "63", fighter1: "Y", fighter2: "KK", fightNumber: 63 },
    { id: "64", fighter1: "LL", fighter2: "OO", fightNumber: 64 },
    { id: "65", fighter1: "PP", fighter2: "QQ", fightNumber: 65 },
    { id: "66", fighter1: "M", fighter2: "II", fightNumber: 66 },
    { id: "67", fighter1: "E", fighter2: "KK", fightNumber: 67 },
    { id: "68", fighter1: "Q", fighter2: "LL", fightNumber: 68 },
    { id: "69", fighter1: "AA", fighter2: "CC", fightNumber: 69 },
    { id: "70", fighter1: "NN", fighter2: "OO", fightNumber: 70 },
    { id: "71", fighter1: "E", fighter2: "FF", fightNumber: 71 },
    { id: "72", fighter1: "G", fighter2: "K", fightNumber: 72 },
    { id: "73", fighter1: "C", fighter2: "Q", fightNumber: 73 },
    { id: "74", fighter1: "D", fighter2: "U", fightNumber: 74 },
    { id: "75", fighter1: "O", fighter2: "OO", fightNumber: 75 },
    { id: "76", fighter1: "U", fighter2: "Z", fightNumber: 76 },
    { id: "77", fighter1: "X", fighter2: "JJ", fightNumber: 77 },
    { id: "78", fighter1: "G", fighter2: "QQ", fightNumber: 78 },
    { id: "79", fighter1: "Q", fighter2: "Z", fightNumber: 79 },
    { id: "80", fighter1: "JJ", fighter2: "NN", fightNumber: 80 },
    { id: "81", fighter1: "F", fighter2: "QQ", fightNumber: 81 },
    { id: "82", fighter1: "QQ", fighter2: "SS", fightNumber: 82 },
    { id: "83", fighter1: "EE", fighter2: "QQ", fightNumber: 83 },
    { id: "84", fighter1: "KK", fighter2: "PP", fightNumber: 84 },
    { id: "85", fighter1: "G", fighter2: "J", fightNumber: 85 },
    { id: "86", fighter1: "EE", fighter2: "FF", fightNumber: 86 },
    { id: "87", fighter1: "D", fighter2: "HH", fightNumber: 87 },
    { id: "88", fighter1: "H", fighter2: "OO", fightNumber: 88 },
    { id: "89", fighter1: "O", fighter2: "R", fightNumber: 89 },
    { id: "90", fighter1: "K", fighter2: "HH", fightNumber: 90 },
    { id: "91", fighter1: "AA", fighter2: "TT", fightNumber: 91 },
    { id: "92", fighter1: "M", fighter2: "CC", fightNumber: 92 },
    { id: "93", fighter1: "U", fighter2: "EE", fightNumber: 93 },
    { id: "94", fighter1: "Z", fighter2: "FF", fightNumber: 94 },
    { id: "95", fighter1: "HH", fighter2: "JJ", fightNumber: 95 },
    { id: "96", fighter1: "C", fighter2: "E", fightNumber: 96 },
    { id: "97", fighter1: "H", fighter2: "I", fightNumber: 97 },
    { id: "98", fighter1: "C", fighter2: "U", fightNumber: 98 },
    { id: "99", fighter1: "F", fighter2: "X", fightNumber: 99 },
    { id: "100", fighter1: "G", fighter2: "SS", fightNumber: 100 },
    { id: "101", fighter1: "W", fighter2: "JJ", fightNumber: 101 },
    { id: "102", fighter1: "C", fighter2: "P", fightNumber: 102 },
    { id: "103", fighter1: "K", fighter2: "W", fightNumber: 103 },
    { id: "104", fighter1: "CC", fighter2: "TT", fightNumber: 104 },
    { id: "105", fighter1: "L", fighter2: "TT", fightNumber: 105 },
    { id: "106", fighter1: "J", fighter2: "EE", fightNumber: 106 },
    { id: "107", fighter1: "M", fighter2: "Y", fightNumber: 107 },
    { id: "108", fighter1: "Z", fighter2: "AA", fightNumber: 108 },
    { id: "109", fighter1: "E", fighter2: "BB", fightNumber: 109 },
    { id: "110", fighter1: "F", fighter2: "I", fightNumber: 110 },
    { id: "111", fighter1: "N", fighter2: "RR", fightNumber: 111 },
    { id: "112", fighter1: "D", fighter2: "NN", fightNumber: 112 },
    { id: "113", fighter1: "L", fighter2: "HH", fightNumber: 113 },
    { id: "114", fighter1: "J", fighter2: "L", fightNumber: 114 },
    { id: "115", fighter1: "L", fighter2: "U", fightNumber: 115 },
    { id: "116", fighter1: "BB", fighter2: "TT", fightNumber: 116 },
    { id: "117", fighter1: "J", fighter2: "U", fightNumber: 117 },
    { id: "118", fighter1: "A", fighter2: "RR", fightNumber: 118 },
    { id: "119", fighter1: "I", fighter2: "SS", fightNumber: 119 },
    { id: "120", fighter1: "J", fighter2: "SS", fightNumber: 120 },
    { id: "121", fighter1: "B", fighter2: "NN", fightNumber: 121 },
    { id: "122", fighter1: "OO", fighter2: "PP", fightNumber: 122 },
    { id: "123", fighter1: "S", fighter2: "X", fightNumber: 123 },
    { id: "124", fighter1: "S", fighter2: "BB", fightNumber: 124 },
    { id: "125", fighter1: "N", fighter2: "II", fightNumber: 125 },
    { id: "126", fighter1: "R", fighter2: "II", fightNumber: 126 },
    { id: "127", fighter1: "S", fighter2: "W", fightNumber: 127 },
    { id: "128", fighter1: "II", fighter2: "NN", fightNumber: 128 },
    { id: "129", fighter1: "Q", fighter2: "Y", fightNumber: 129 },
    { id: "130", fighter1: "B", fighter2: "W", fightNumber: 130 },
    { id: "131", fighter1: "E", fighter2: "M", fightNumber: 131 },
    { id: "132", fighter1: "GG", fighter2: "QQ", fightNumber: 132 },
    { id: "133", fighter1: "S", fighter2: "GG", fightNumber: 133 },
    { id: "134", fighter1: "S", fighter2: "PP", fightNumber: 134 },
    { id: "135", fighter1: "B", fighter2: "GG", fightNumber: 135 },
    { id: "136", fighter1: "M", fighter2: "NN", fightNumber: 136 },
    { id: "137", fighter1: "F", fighter2: "Y", fightNumber: 137 },
    { id: "138", fighter1: "I", fighter2: "R", fightNumber: 138 },
    { id: "139", fighter1: "KK", fighter2: "SS", fightNumber: 139 },
    { id: "140", fighter1: "D", fighter2: "GG", fightNumber: 140 },
    { id: "141", fighter1: "H", fighter2: "AA", fightNumber: 141 },
    { id: "142", fighter1: "A", fighter2: "MM", fightNumber: 142 },
    { id: "143", fighter1: "NN", fighter2: "TT", fightNumber: 143 },
    { id: "144", fighter1: "L", fighter2: "LL", fightNumber: 144 },
    { id: "145", fighter1: "S", fighter2: "LL", fightNumber: 145 },
    { id: "146", fighter1: "O", fighter2: "CC", fightNumber: 146 },
    { id: "147", fighter1: "GG", fighter2: "SS", fightNumber: 147 },
    { id: "148", fighter1: "N", fighter2: "HH", fightNumber: 148 },
    { id: "149", fighter1: "A", fighter2: "II", fightNumber: 149 },
    { id: "150", fighter1: "B", fighter2: "LL", fightNumber: 150 },
    { id: "151", fighter1: "K", fighter2: "M", fightNumber: 151 },
    { id: "152", fighter1: "A", fighter2: "N", fightNumber: 152 },
    { id: "153", fighter1: "M", fighter2: "HH", fightNumber: 153 },
    { id: "154", fighter1: "A", fighter2: "E", fightNumber: 154 },
    { id: "155", fighter1: "N", fighter2: "GG", fightNumber: 155 },
    { id: "156", fighter1: "AA", fighter2: "RR", fightNumber: 156 },
    { id: "157", fighter1: "B", fighter2: "I", fightNumber: 157 },
    { id: "158", fighter1: "C", fighter2: "Y", fightNumber: 158 },
    { id: "159", fighter1: "RR", fighter2: "TT", fightNumber: 159 },
    { id: "160", fighter1: "N", fighter2: "joker", fightNumber: 160 },
    { id: "161", fighter1: "JJ", fighter2: "RR", fightNumber: 161 },
    { id: "162", fighter1: "A", fighter2: "B", fightNumber: 162 },
  ];
  function rearrangeFightNumbers(data) {
    const totaldata = data.length;

    // Helper function to find the last fight number for a fighter
    function findLastFightNumber(fighterName) {
      const fights = data.filter(
        (fight) =>
          fight.fighter1 === fighterName || fight.fighter2 === fighterName
      );
      return Math.max(...fights.map((fight) => fight.fightNumber));
    }

    // Calculate new fight numbers for each fighter with the desired gap
    const uniqueFighters = Array.from(
      new Set(
        data
          .map((fight) => fight.fighter1)
          .concat(data.map((fight) => fight.fighter2))
      )
    );

    for (const fighter of uniqueFighters) {
      const fighterFights = data.filter(
        (fight) => fight.fighter1 === fighter || fight.fighter2 === fighter
      );
      let totalFights = fighterFights.length;
      let minGap = 10;
      let maxGap = 30;

      // Adjust the gap if necessary to fit the desired criteria
      while ((totalFights - 1) * minGap > totaldata) {
        minGap--;
      }
      while ((totalFights - 1) * maxGap < totaldata) {
        maxGap++;
      }

      let currentFightNumber = findLastFightNumber(fighter) + minGap;

      for (const fight of fighterFights) {
        fight.fightNumber = Math.min(currentFightNumber, data.length);
        currentFightNumber +=
          minGap + Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxGap - minGap + 1));
      }
    }

    // Sort the fights based on their new fight numbers
    data.sort((a, b) => a.fightNumber - b.fightNumber);

    // Ensure fight numbers are unique and within the range of 1 to 162
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      data[i].fightNumber = Math.min(i + 1, totaldata);
    }

    return data;
  }
  // Usage:
  const updatedData = rearrangeFightNumbers(data);
  console.log(updatedData);
```

Comment: Can you create a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example? With minimal input data and state your expected output to help understand your question more easily.

Comment: Done. Added minimal example and target. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure you completely understand the concept of _minimal_.

Comment: You have provided too much implementation details - but you did not explain the business case. What are these fighters, what are they doing, what is a `fight`, what is the meaning of the numbers, what is the rule or formula that you want to codify, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. Please, see the updated details. And let me know if i missed something. I'll be glad to learn more from you. Thank you

Comment: Why rearrange instead of generate? Are the matchups already predetermined, and already have an id? Is there a reason the input data isn't just a list of matchups *without a `fightNumber`*, which the desired funcition adds?  Or even more simply, why isn't the input just a list of fighters, with a function that generates N matchups randomly and evenly, and then schedules them?  What should happen if the constraint (a fighter's next fight must be between 10 and 30 fights later) is not possible for all matchups?

Comment: If it's not possible to make it 10 or 30 fights later due to not enough fights remaining, then it can go below 10... But it can never go below 3.  

I came up with rearrange coz before i tried to regenerate it but i didn't meet the expected result. So i came up with this scenario. Tho if there's a regenerate function that can be suggested, i'm willing to work on it.

Comment: The bounty attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: I was hoping he/she could help me though. That's kinda sad.

Comment: What's the logic for generating these fights? I'm assuming not everyone is fighting everyone, you seem to have 47 fighters and 162 fights.

Comment: The [mre] for this would have input stripped down like in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76808231/8910547), and a simplified problem statement such as "given the matchups below, schedule them so that any two fights with the same fighter is separated by N fights that don't include that fighter". If that makes sense, I can update your question so that more people can understand it and also so that it might be of more general use to others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You can't just naively reorder matchups.

I don't have a CS or combinatorial mathematics degree (nor any other degree
for that matter) nor any background in theoretical computer science. Still, I know this is a non-trivial combinatorial mathematics problem.

Your data has 47 fighters. There are 1081 possible matchups (`f*(f-1)/2`). Each fighter is in 46 matchups. So for any one fighter, there are `1081 - 46` matchups that don't include that fighter. This is the number of available fights to create separation between that fighter's fights. Thus, the theoretical maximum possible separation for all the fighters fights is `1081 - 46)/47`, or 22. If this is not obvious, write out all the matchups for 6 fighters. The math should then make sense.

> ‼️ I did some Monte Carlo testing, and it appears that the ***true upper bound*** is non-linear, with the value dropping
> further and further below my calculated upper bound. My monte carlo testing for 46 fighters yielded a max
> separation of only 15 for all iterations, versus the 21 my formula above yields.

The scenario in your question only includes 162 of those 1081 possible matchups. You would think this makes the problem easier, but not really. The solution space to search is still humungous! There are 1.2296942187394488e+289 (`162!`) possible schedules for those 162 matchups. Thats:

```
12,296,942,187,394,488,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000  possible schedules.
```

Not only that, depending on the matchups chosen, maximum possible separation may be less than the theoretical maximum. You can see this for the extreme case: Set up 20 matchups for fighter `A`, and only 18 matchups that don't include `A`. You will be forced to schedule at least one back-to-back fight for `A`. In your case, the fights are evenly distributed, except for the `joker`, so I think the 22 upper bound is still possible, but no more, as the same upper bound formula still applies.

> ‼️ In other words, it will be impossible to find a schedule with a separation of 23. Don't even think about 30. The true max sep may  be even lower, as my Monte Carlo testing seems to indicate.

More importantly:

> ‼️ The number of schedules with a separation of 22 is a tiny tiny tiny fraction of that huge number I show above. You're looking for an atom in a haystack. No CPU is fast enough to try all possibilities.

### You need an intelligent algorithm

This means you have to either:

- come up with an algorithm that "knows" exactly how to find that optimum schedule, if possible
- come up with an heuristic algorithm that incorporates some kind of understanding of the problem, knowing which choices are more likely to produce better results, and most importantly, avoid dead ends. It won't find the optimal answer, but it will find a pretty good one in a reasonable time.

I didn't have the time to figure out what you were trying to do with your code, but I could tell it wasn't either of the above.

I came up with a heuristic algorithm.

Below is your input data, stripped of extraneous stuff. My solution operates on this. If necessary, you can modify it to operate on your data structure, but as others have pointed out, problems are best solved if they are first stripped down to their [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) form.

```js
const matchups = [
    ['V', 'DD'],
    ['R', 'V'],
    ['J', 'X'],
    ['H', 'KK'],
    ['DD', 'MM'],
    ['V', 'Z'],
    ['V', 'SS'],
    ['C', 'V'],
    ['P', 'joker'],
    ['P', 'LL'],
    ['Y', 'QQ'],
    ['R', 'OO'],
    ['D', 'R'],
    ['X', 'DD'],
    ['P', 'W'],
    ['Y', 'BB'],
    ['D', 'O'],
    ['W', 'CC'],
    ['JJ', 'KK'],
    ['I', 'T'],
    ['T', 'MM'],
    ['R', 'RR'],
    ['T', 'FF'],
    ['G', 'DD'],
    ['L', 'FF'],
    ['S', 'EE'],
    ['BB', 'GG'],
    ['E', 'MM'],
    ['J', 'T'],
    ['V', 'X'],
    ['CC', 'DD'],
    ['Q', 'EE'],
    ['C', 'T'],
    ['H', 'U'],
    ['Z', 'II'],
    ['A', 'JJ'],
    ['H', 'T'],
    ['D', 'OO'],
    ['L', 'O'],
    ['T', 'DD'],
    ['F', 'MM'],
    ['N', 'V'],
    ['X', 'EE'],
    ['G', 'PP'],
    ['I', 'Q'],
    ['K', 'CC'],
    ['F', 'DD'],
    ['Q', 'AA'],
    ['AA', 'PP'],
    ['LL', 'TT'],
    ['P', 'Z'],
    ['W', 'FF'],
    ['MM', 'RR'],
    ['FF', 'II'],
    ['F', 'P'],
    ['G', 'MM'],
    ['O', 'BB'],
    ['H', 'PP'],
    ['K', 'O'],
    ['P', 'BB'],
    ['HH', 'KK'],
    ['B', 'K'],
    ['Y', 'KK'],
    ['LL', 'OO'],
    ['PP', 'QQ'],
    ['M', 'II'],
    ['E', 'KK'],
    ['Q', 'LL'],
    ['AA', 'CC'],
    ['NN', 'OO'],
    ['E', 'FF'],
    ['G', 'K'],
    ['C', 'Q'],
    ['D', 'U'],
    ['O', 'OO'],
    ['U', 'Z'],
    ['X', 'JJ'],
    ['G', 'QQ'],
    ['Q', 'Z'],
    ['JJ', 'NN'],
    ['F', 'QQ'],
    ['QQ', 'SS'],
    ['EE', 'QQ'],
    ['KK', 'PP'],
    ['G', 'J'],
    ['EE', 'FF'],
    ['D', 'HH'],
    ['H', 'OO'],
    ['O', 'R'],
    ['K', 'HH'],
    ['AA', 'TT'],
    ['M', 'CC'],
    ['U', 'EE'],
    ['Z', 'FF'],
    ['HH', 'JJ'],
    ['C', 'E'],
    ['H', 'I'],
    ['C', 'U'],
    ['F', 'X'],
    ['G', 'SS'],
    ['W', 'JJ'],
    ['C', 'P'],
    ['K', 'W'],
    ['CC', 'TT'],
    ['L', 'TT'],
    ['J', 'EE'],
    ['M', 'Y'],
    ['Z', 'AA'],
    ['E', 'BB'],
    ['F', 'I'],
    ['N', 'RR'],
    ['D', 'NN'],
    ['L', 'HH'],
    ['J', 'L'],
    ['L', 'U'],
    ['BB', 'TT'],
    ['J', 'U'],
    ['A', 'RR'],
    ['I', 'SS'],
    ['J', 'SS'],
    ['B', 'NN'],
    ['OO', 'PP'],
    ['S', 'X'],
    ['S', 'BB'],
    ['N', 'II'],
    ['R', 'II'],
    ['S', 'W'],
    ['II', 'NN'],
    ['Q', 'Y'],
    ['B', 'W'],
    ['E', 'M'],
    ['GG', 'QQ'],
    ['S', 'GG'],
    ['S', 'PP'],
    ['B', 'GG'],
    ['M', 'NN'],
    ['F', 'Y'],
    ['I', 'R'],
    ['KK', 'SS'],
    ['D', 'GG'],
    ['H', 'AA'],
    ['A', 'MM'],
    ['NN', 'TT'],
    ['L', 'LL'],
    ['S', 'LL'],
    ['O', 'CC'],
    ['GG', 'SS'],
    ['N', 'HH'],
    ['A', 'II'],
    ['B', 'LL'],
    ['K', 'M'],
    ['A', 'N'],
    ['M', 'HH'],
    ['A', 'E'],
    ['N', 'GG'],
    ['AA', 'RR'],
    ['B', 'I'],
    ['C', 'Y'],
    ['RR', 'TT'],
    ['N', 'joker'],
    ['JJ', 'RR'],
    ['A', 'B']
]
```

Below is the core of the algorithm. In essence, as it iteratively schedules
fights, it continually recalculates which matchups have the greater "need" to be
scheduled next ("schedule pressure").

For example, say a matchup that has fighters who each have only one unscheduled
matchup remaining. It will be easy to find a slot with the `minSep` for them
later, so the scheduling pressure for that matchup is low. But another matchup
has one fighter with 6 unscheduled fights remaining, and the second fighter
with 4 remaining. It's going to be much harder to fit all those remaining
fights into the remaining slots while maintaining `minSep`, so the pressure to
schedule them now is much higher.

> The algorithm is a [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm)
> that makes scheduling decision by always scheduling matchups with higher
> scheduling pressure as soon as possible.

```js
function scheduleMatchups(matchups, minSep) {
    const unscheduledMatchups = [...matchups];
    const schedule = [];
    const fighterLastMatchup = {};
    let fightNum = 0;
    let complete = true;
    outer: while (unscheduledMatchups.length > 0) {
        fightNum++;
        sortBySchedulingPressure(unscheduledMatchups);
        for (let i = 0; i < unscheduledMatchups.length; i++) {
            const mu = unscheduledMatchups[i];
            const f1Last = fighterLastMatchup[mu[0]] ?? -minSep;
            const f2Last = fighterLastMatchup[mu[1]] ?? -minSep;
            if (fightNum - f1Last >= minSep &&
                fightNum - f2Last >= minSep) {
                const smu = { fightNum: fightNum, matchup: mu };
                schedule.push(smu);
                fighterLastMatchup[mu[0]] = fightNum;
                fighterLastMatchup[mu[1]] = fightNum;
                unscheduledMatchups.splice(i, 1);
                continue outer;
            }
        }
        complete = false;
        break;
    }
    return { schedule, complete };
}

function sortBySchedulingPressure(matchups) {
    const fToMu = mapFightersToMatchups(matchups);
    // sort by pressure, desc
    matchups.sort((mu1, mu2) => {
        const m1f1 = fToMu[mu1[0]].length;
        const m1f2 = fToMu[mu1[1]].length;
        const m1Min = Math.min(m1f1, m1f2);
        const m1Max = Math.max(m1f1, m1f2);
        const m2f1 = fToMu[mu2[0]].length;
        const m2f2 = fToMu[mu2[1]].length;
        const m2Min = Math.min(m2f1, m2f2);
        const m2Max = Math.max(m2f1, m2f2);
        if (m1Min != m2Min)
            return m2Min - m1Min;
        if (m1Max != m2Max)
            return m2Max - m1Max;
        return 0;
    });
}

function mapFightersToMatchups(matchups) {
    return matchups
        .reduce(function (f2m, mu) {
        if (mu[0] in f2m) {
            f2m[mu[0]].push(mu);
        }
        else {
            f2m[mu[0]] = [mu];
        }
        if (mu[1] in f2m) {
            f2m[mu[1]].push(mu);
        }
        else {
            f2m[mu[1]] = [mu];
        }
        return f2m;
    }, {});
}
```

This function takes the matchups and a target separation value and calls the above code to try and make a schedule with that much separation between every fight. If it fails, it tries again with smaller and smaller target separations until there is success:

```js
function findBestSchedule(matchups, targetSep) {
    console.group(`\nScheduling ${matchups.length} matchups...`);
    for (let sep = targetSep; sep >= 0; sep--) {
        const { schedule, complete } = scheduleMatchups(matchups, sep);
        if (complete) {
            console.log(`✅ found schedule with minimum separation of ${sep}.`);
            console.groupEnd();
            return { schedule, sep };
        }
        else {
            console.log(`❌ failed using minimum separation of ${sep}. Hit dead end with ${matchups.length - schedule.length} matchups remaining to schedule}.`);
        }
    }
    console.groupEnd();
    throw new Error('this should never happen');
}
```

You can call/test it like this:

```js
function printScheduleInfo(schedule) {
    console.group('schedule:');
    schedule.forEach(smu => {
        console.log(smu);
    });
    console.groupEnd();
}

const { schedule, sep } = findBestSchedule(matchups, 30);
printScheduleInfo(schedule);
console.log(`Found schedule with minimum separation of ${sep}.`);
```

which yields:

```
Scheduling 162 matchups...
  ❌ failed using minimum separation of 22. Hit dead end with 141 matchups remaining to schedule}.
  ❌ failed using minimum separation of 21. Hit dead end with 141 matchups remaining to schedule}.
  ❌ failed using minimum separation of 20. Hit dead end with 128 matchups remaining to schedule}.
  ❌ failed using minimum separation of 19. Hit dead end with 127 matchups remaining to schedule}.
  ❌ failed using minimum separation of 18. Hit dead end with 42 matchups remaining to schedule}.
  ❌ failed using minimum separation of 17. Hit dead end with 18 matchups remaining to schedule}.
  ✅ found schedule with minimum separation of 16.
```

I didn't include the schedule it found, as this post is too long already.

### Taking it further, to Monte Carlo

This algorithm, given the same input, will find the *exact* same answer every time. If you shuffle the input, it will come up with a different answer, maybe better, maybe worse. So I used a [Monte Carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method), shuffling the input and rerunning the algorithm.

Here is the distribution of the results from 10,000 iterations:

```
12 | 5
13 | -- 137
14 | --------------------------------- 1554
15 | -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 4497
16 | -------------------------------------------------------------------------- 3386
17 | -------- 417
18 | 4
10000 values plotted with an average of 15.2389
```

This demonstrates two things:

- The more optimal solution is clearly harder to find. Much harder. I suspect if I ran it a million times it might find a schedule with a minimum separation of 19. Maybe a 20, but I doubt it.
- The histogram tails off very quickly on the other end too, resulting in schedules with less than 14 separation less than 1.5% of the time, and none below 12. That's pretty good!

If you're ok with a range like that, then you can call my algorithm just once. If you really need to
find a more optimal answer, you can shuffle the input and rerun it as many times as you can afford,
and keep the best answer it finds.

Anyway, I gotta get back to real life now! Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect. This is what i'm looking for. I'm a beginner so having this step by step explanation is very helpful for my end. Thank you so much for this. Super appreciated.

Comment: @Dark glad this helped. I noticed an off-by-one error on how it interpreted minSep. I updated the code in my answer. I also better explained the logic behind both the theoretical upper bound and my heuristic algorithm. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand how the code that is changing `fightNumber` for each fighter fights works to sort them correctly. It seems to overwrite gap corrections with correcting the gaps next fighters. Maybe rather algorithm for regenerating:

- Do checks for each next fight from all of unadded fights

  - check for fighters that had fight recently
  - choose fight, which has fighter waiting for next fight the longest
  - add fight if conditions met else log error
- convert generated content to have desired property names and ids

In basic, the algorithm first lists most fights with unique fighter, than continues adding the rest so they do have specified minimal gap.

Here is what I got from testing so far:

```js
"use strict";
  const data = [
    { id: "1", fighter1: "V", fighter2: "DD", fightNumber: 1 },
    { id: "2", fighter1: "R", fighter2: "V", fightNumber: 2 },
    { id: "3", fighter1: "J", fighter2: "X", fightNumber: 3 },
    { id: "4", fighter1: "H", fighter2: "KK", fightNumber: 4 },
    { id: "5", fighter1: "DD", fighter2: "MM", fightNumber: 5 },
    { id: "6", fighter1: "V", fighter2: "Z", fightNumber: 6 },
    { id: "7", fighter1: "V", fighter2: "SS", fightNumber: 7 },
    { id: "8", fighter1: "C", fighter2: "V", fightNumber: 8 },
    { id: "9", fighter1: "P", fighter2: "joker", fightNumber: 9 },
    { id: "10", fighter1: "P", fighter2: "LL", fightNumber: 10 },
    { id: "11", fighter1: "Y", fighter2: "QQ", fightNumber: 11 },
    { id: "12", fighter1: "R", fighter2: "OO", fightNumber: 12 },
    { id: "13", fighter1: "D", fighter2: "R", fightNumber: 13 },
    { id: "14", fighter1: "X", fighter2: "DD", fightNumber: 14 },
    { id: "15", fighter1: "P", fighter2: "W", fightNumber: 15 },
    { id: "16", fighter1: "Y", fighter2: "BB", fightNumber: 16 },
    { id: "17", fighter1: "D", fighter2: "O", fightNumber: 17 },
    { id: "18", fighter1: "W", fighter2: "CC", fightNumber: 18 },
    { id: "19", fighter1: "JJ", fighter2: "KK", fightNumber: 19 },
    { id: "20", fighter1: "I", fighter2: "T", fightNumber: 20 },
    { id: "21", fighter1: "T", fighter2: "MM", fightNumber: 21 },
    { id: "22", fighter1: "R", fighter2: "RR", fightNumber: 22 },
    { id: "23", fighter1: "T", fighter2: "FF", fightNumber: 23 },
    { id: "24", fighter1: "G", fighter2: "DD", fightNumber: 24 },
    { id: "25", fighter1: "L", fighter2: "FF", fightNumber: 25 },
    { id: "26", fighter1: "S", fighter2: "EE", fightNumber: 26 },
    { id: "27", fighter1: "BB", fighter2: "GG", fightNumber: 27 },
    { id: "28", fighter1: "E", fighter2: "MM", fightNumber: 28 },
    { id: "29", fighter1: "J", fighter2: "T", fightNumber: 29 },
    { id: "30", fighter1: "V", fighter2: "X", fightNumber: 30 },
    { id: "31", fighter1: "CC", fighter2: "DD", fightNumber: 31 },
    { id: "32", fighter1: "Q", fighter2: "EE", fightNumber: 32 },
    { id: "33", fighter1: "C", fighter2: "T", fightNumber: 33 },
    { id: "34", fighter1: "H", fighter2: "U", fightNumber: 34 },
    { id: "35", fighter1: "Z", fighter2: "II", fightNumber: 35 },
    { id: "36", fighter1: "A", fighter2: "JJ", fightNumber: 36 },
    { id: "37", fighter1: "H", fighter2: "T", fightNumber: 37 },
    { id: "38", fighter1: "D", fighter2: "OO", fightNumber: 38 },
    { id: "39", fighter1: "L", fighter2: "O", fightNumber: 39 },
    { id: "40", fighter1: "T", fighter2: "DD", fightNumber: 40 },
    { id: "41", fighter1: "F", fighter2: "MM", fightNumber: 41 },
    { id: "42", fighter1: "N", fighter2: "V", fightNumber: 42 },
    { id: "43", fighter1: "X", fighter2: "EE", fightNumber: 43 },
    { id: "44", fighter1: "G", fighter2: "PP", fightNumber: 44 },
    { id: "45", fighter1: "I", fighter2: "Q", fightNumber: 45 },
    { id: "46", fighter1: "K", fighter2: "CC", fightNumber: 46 },
    { id: "47", fighter1: "F", fighter2: "DD", fightNumber: 47 },
    { id: "48", fighter1: "Q", fighter2: "AA", fightNumber: 48 },
    { id: "49", fighter1: "AA", fighter2: "PP", fightNumber: 49 },
    { id: "50", fighter1: "LL", fighter2: "TT", fightNumber: 50 },
    { id: "51", fighter1: "P", fighter2: "Z", fightNumber: 51 },
    { id: "52", fighter1: "W", fighter2: "FF", fightNumber: 52 },
    { id: "53", fighter1: "MM", fighter2: "RR", fightNumber: 53 },
    { id: "54", fighter1: "FF", fighter2: "II", fightNumber: 54 },
    { id: "55", fighter1: "F", fighter2: "P", fightNumber: 55 },
    { id: "56", fighter1: "G", fighter2: "MM", fightNumber: 56 },
    { id: "57", fighter1: "O", fighter2: "BB", fightNumber: 57 },
    { id: "58", fighter1: "H", fighter2: "PP", fightNumber: 58 },
    { id: "59", fighter1: "K", fighter2: "O", fightNumber: 59 },
    { id: "60", fighter1: "P", fighter2: "BB", fightNumber: 60 },
    { id: "61", fighter1: "HH", fighter2: "KK", fightNumber: 61 },
    { id: "62", fighter1: "B", fighter2: "K", fightNumber: 62 },
    { id: "63", fighter1: "Y", fighter2: "KK", fightNumber: 63 },
    { id: "64", fighter1: "LL", fighter2: "OO", fightNumber: 64 },
    { id: "65", fighter1: "PP", fighter2: "QQ", fightNumber: 65 },
    { id: "66", fighter1: "M", fighter2: "II", fightNumber: 66 },
    { id: "67", fighter1: "E", fighter2: "KK", fightNumber: 67 },
    { id: "68", fighter1: "Q", fighter2: "LL", fightNumber: 68 },
    { id: "69", fighter1: "AA", fighter2: "CC", fightNumber: 69 },
    { id: "70", fighter1: "NN", fighter2: "OO", fightNumber: 70 },
    { id: "71", fighter1: "E", fighter2: "FF", fightNumber: 71 },
    { id: "72", fighter1: "G", fighter2: "K", fightNumber: 72 },
    { id: "73", fighter1: "C", fighter2: "Q", fightNumber: 73 },
    { id: "74", fighter1: "D", fighter2: "U", fightNumber: 74 },
    { id: "75", fighter1: "O", fighter2: "OO", fightNumber: 75 },
    { id: "76", fighter1: "U", fighter2: "Z", fightNumber: 76 },
    { id: "77", fighter1: "X", fighter2: "JJ", fightNumber: 77 },
    { id: "78", fighter1: "G", fighter2: "QQ", fightNumber: 78 },
    { id: "79", fighter1: "Q", fighter2: "Z", fightNumber: 79 },
    { id: "80", fighter1: "JJ", fighter2: "NN", fightNumber: 80 },
    { id: "81", fighter1: "F", fighter2: "QQ", fightNumber: 81 },
    { id: "82", fighter1: "QQ", fighter2: "SS", fightNumber: 82 },
    { id: "83", fighter1: "EE", fighter2: "QQ", fightNumber: 83 },
    { id: "84", fighter1: "KK", fighter2: "PP", fightNumber: 84 },
    { id: "85", fighter1: "G", fighter2: "J", fightNumber: 85 },
    { id: "86", fighter1: "EE", fighter2: "FF", fightNumber: 86 },
    { id: "87", fighter1: "D", fighter2: "HH", fightNumber: 87 },
    { id: "88", fighter1: "H", fighter2: "OO", fightNumber: 88 },
    { id: "89", fighter1: "O", fighter2: "R", fightNumber: 89 },
    { id: "90", fighter1: "K", fighter2: "HH", fightNumber: 90 },
    { id: "91", fighter1: "AA", fighter2: "TT", fightNumber: 91 },
    { id: "92", fighter1: "M", fighter2: "CC", fightNumber: 92 },
    { id: "93", fighter1: "U", fighter2: "EE", fightNumber: 93 },
    { id: "94", fighter1: "Z", fighter2: "FF", fightNumber: 94 },
    { id: "95", fighter1: "HH", fighter2: "JJ", fightNumber: 95 },
    { id: "96", fighter1: "C", fighter2: "E", fightNumber: 96 },
    { id: "97", fighter1: "H", fighter2: "I", fightNumber: 97 },
    { id: "98", fighter1: "C", fighter2: "U", fightNumber: 98 },
    { id: "99", fighter1: "F", fighter2: "X", fightNumber: 99 },
    { id: "100", fighter1: "G", fighter2: "SS", fightNumber: 100 },
    { id: "101", fighter1: "W", fighter2: "JJ", fightNumber: 101 },
    { id: "102", fighter1: "C", fighter2: "P", fightNumber: 102 },
    { id: "103", fighter1: "K", fighter2: "W", fightNumber: 103 },
    { id: "104", fighter1: "CC", fighter2: "TT", fightNumber: 104 },
    { id: "105", fighter1: "L", fighter2: "TT", fightNumber: 105 },
    { id: "106", fighter1: "J", fighter2: "EE", fightNumber: 106 },
    { id: "107", fighter1: "M", fighter2: "Y", fightNumber: 107 },
    { id: "108", fighter1: "Z", fighter2: "AA", fightNumber: 108 },
    { id: "109", fighter1: "E", fighter2: "BB", fightNumber: 109 },
    { id: "110", fighter1: "F", fighter2: "I", fightNumber: 110 },
    { id: "111", fighter1: "N", fighter2: "RR", fightNumber: 111 },
    { id: "112", fighter1: "D", fighter2: "NN", fightNumber: 112 },
    { id: "113", fighter1: "L", fighter2: "HH", fightNumber: 113 },
    { id: "114", fighter1: "J", fighter2: "L", fightNumber: 114 },
    { id: "115", fighter1: "L", fighter2: "U", fightNumber: 115 },
    { id: "116", fighter1: "BB", fighter2: "TT", fightNumber: 116 },
    { id: "117", fighter1: "J", fighter2: "U", fightNumber: 117 },
    { id: "118", fighter1: "A", fighter2: "RR", fightNumber: 118 },
    { id: "119", fighter1: "I", fighter2: "SS", fightNumber: 119 },
    { id: "120", fighter1: "J", fighter2: "SS", fightNumber: 120 },
    { id: "121", fighter1: "B", fighter2: "NN", fightNumber: 121 },
    { id: "122", fighter1: "OO", fighter2: "PP", fightNumber: 122 },
    { id: "123", fighter1: "S", fighter2: "X", fightNumber: 123 },
    { id: "124", fighter1: "S", fighter2: "BB", fightNumber: 124 },
    { id: "125", fighter1: "N", fighter2: "II", fightNumber: 125 },
    { id: "126", fighter1: "R", fighter2: "II", fightNumber: 126 },
    { id: "127", fighter1: "S", fighter2: "W", fightNumber: 127 },
    { id: "128", fighter1: "II", fighter2: "NN", fightNumber: 128 },
    { id: "129", fighter1: "Q", fighter2: "Y", fightNumber: 129 },
    { id: "130", fighter1: "B", fighter2: "W", fightNumber: 130 },
    { id: "131", fighter1: "E", fighter2: "M", fightNumber: 131 },
    { id: "132", fighter1: "GG", fighter2: "QQ", fightNumber: 132 },
    { id: "133", fighter1: "S", fighter2: "GG", fightNumber: 133 },
    { id: "134", fighter1: "S", fighter2: "PP", fightNumber: 134 },
    { id: "135", fighter1: "B", fighter2: "GG", fightNumber: 135 },
    { id: "136", fighter1: "M", fighter2: "NN", fightNumber: 136 },
    { id: "137", fighter1: "F", fighter2: "Y", fightNumber: 137 },
    { id: "138", fighter1: "I", fighter2: "R", fightNumber: 138 },
    { id: "139", fighter1: "KK", fighter2: "SS", fightNumber: 139 },
    { id: "140", fighter1: "D", fighter2: "GG", fightNumber: 140 },
    { id: "141", fighter1: "H", fighter2: "AA", fightNumber: 141 },
    { id: "142", fighter1: "A", fighter2: "MM", fightNumber: 142 },
    { id: "143", fighter1: "NN", fighter2: "TT", fightNumber: 143 },
    { id: "144", fighter1: "L", fighter2: "LL", fightNumber: 144 },
    { id: "145", fighter1: "S", fighter2: "LL", fightNumber: 145 },
    { id: "146", fighter1: "O", fighter2: "CC", fightNumber: 146 },
    { id: "147", fighter1: "GG", fighter2: "SS", fightNumber: 147 },
    { id: "148", fighter1: "N", fighter2: "HH", fightNumber: 148 },
    { id: "149", fighter1: "A", fighter2: "II", fightNumber: 149 },
    { id: "150", fighter1: "B", fighter2: "LL", fightNumber: 150 },
    { id: "151", fighter1: "K", fighter2: "M", fightNumber: 151 },
    { id: "152", fighter1: "A", fighter2: "N", fightNumber: 152 },
    { id: "153", fighter1: "M", fighter2: "HH", fightNumber: 153 },
    { id: "154", fighter1: "A", fighter2: "E", fightNumber: 154 },
    { id: "155", fighter1: "N", fighter2: "GG", fightNumber: 155 },
    { id: "156", fighter1: "AA", fighter2: "RR", fightNumber: 156 },
    { id: "157", fighter1: "B", fighter2: "I", fightNumber: 157 },
    { id: "158", fighter1: "C", fighter2: "Y", fightNumber: 158 },
    { id: "159", fighter1: "RR", fighter2: "TT", fightNumber: 159 },
    { id: "160", fighter1: "N", fighter2: "joker", fightNumber: 160 },
    { id: "161", fighter1: "JJ", fighter2: "RR", fightNumber: 161 },
    { id: "162", fighter1: "A", fighter2: "B", fightNumber: 162 },
  ];
var minGap = 10, maxGap = 30, minFrom = 0, maxFrom = 0;
// Array:mins = fighters waiting number:minGap of mathces
// Array:maxs = uniqueFighters that start
// at index number:maxGap * 2
var mins = [""], maxs = [""], fights = [["", ""]];

var fightsByfighter = {}, generated = [["", ""]];
// does what was used for creating `uniquFighters` and
// `fighterFights`, because I didn't initially notice
+function(data){
  var i = maxGap * 2, id = 0, j = "";
  maxs = new Array(i);
  function updtFighter(name1, name2) {
    // checks if property of string:name1 exists
    fightsByfighter[name1] instanceof Array ?
      // adds next match oponent to existng name
      fightsByfighter[name1].push(name2) :
      // sets new propety and adds name to Array:maxs
      fightsByfighter[maxs[i++] = name1] = [name2];
  }
  for (j in data)
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(data, j)) {
      fights[id++] = [data[j].fighter1, data[j].fighter2];
      updtFighter(data[j].fighter1, data[j].fighter2);
      updtFighter(data[j].fighter2, data[j].fighter1);
    }
  // !fightsByfighter is only for testing purpose!
  // if needed use different object structure for map
}(data);

// list is generated from beginning. fighters from fights
// are appended to Array:mins, when it's length reaches
// number:minGap * 2 fighters from the beginnig start
// getting appended back to Array:maxs. Later When
// Array:mins.length reaches index in Array:maxs where is
// unused fighter it represents crossing number:maxGap
+function(fights){
  generated.length = mins.length = 0;
  function countScore(s, n) {
    n = maxs.indexOf(s, maxFrom);
    return n !== -1 ? n0 - maxFrom : 0;
  }
  function addFight() {
    var id = -1, score = 0, name0 = "", name1 = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < fights.length; i++) {
      name0 = fights[i][0];
      name1 = fights[i][1];
      // checks Array:mins for names
      // that would repeat fight too early
      if (mins.indexOf(name0, minFrom) != -1 ||
        mins.indexOf(name1, minFrom) != -1)
        continue;
      // rest of loop should calculate score to find with
      // fighters that are waiting the longest,
      // and to ensure that everyone is spread out
      generated.push([name0, name1]);
      fights[i] = fights.slice(-1)[0];
      fights.length--;
      break;
    }
    if (i === fights.length && id === -1)
      // if number:minGap condition can't be met log error
      console.error("couldn't fit:",
        fights.slice(-1)[fights.length-- * 0],
        "at: ", generated.length);
    // removes names which are ready again
    // after number:minGap fights from Array:mins
    i = (maxFrom = mins.push(name0, name1)) - minGap * 2;
    if (i >= 0)
      maxs.push(mins[minFrom = i], mins[i + 1]);
    else
      maxFrom = maxGap * 2;
  }
  for (var l = fights.length; l-- > 0;)
    addFight();
  return generated;
}(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fights)));
console.log(generated.join("; ").split(",").join(" vs. "));
```

There can be seen partial succes in result of code snippet, that has error for last few fights to be added. Lowering `minGap` doesn't fix the issue, it's rather the algorithm being uncomplete (missing part for `maxGap`).

Comment: Hello. Thank you for answering. Your codes are working on my side also but somehow, the accepted answer is much accurate. Tho i'm still thankful for taking time to help me. Appreciated. ^_^